# Route resolve going through even on a bad request

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I need to resolve two service calls before I create my view like this

```
$stateProvider
    .state('parent', {
        url: '/parent',
        abstract: true,
        resolve: {
            resolveService: function($q, personService, jobService) {
                return $q.all({
                    persons: personService.getPersons(),
                    jobs: jobService.getJobs()
                })
            }
        }
    })

    .state('parent.child', {
        url: '/child'
    })
```

One service looks something like this

```
 function getPersons() {
    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://myPersonApi'
    }

    return $http(req)
    .then(getPersonsComplete)
    .catch(getPersonsFailed)

    function getPersonsComplete(response) {
        return response.data.persons;
    }

    function getPersonsFailed(error) {
        //log error
        return error;
    }
}
```

I tried it out but got a `CORS` error in `dev` which is fully expected but the strange thing that even though the `$http` was rejected the route was resolved.

I debugged and see I get a `HTTP status code 405` and the `getPersonFailed` function is ran but still the `$q.all` gets resolved. I tried to change to just a `$q.reject` and then it worked as expected and the route never materialized.

Note the error object of the `$http` call says `status: 0` and `statusText: ""`

Is the `$http promise` not handled in the same way as `$q` one?

Comment: $q.all takes an array of promises, try $q.all([persons, jobs])...

Comment: @Hitmands `$q.all` should work with an array or an object according to the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because your catch handler is resolving the promise by returning a string. Try explicitly rejecting the promise in the catch or just remove the catch altogether.

```
function getPersonsFailed(error) {
    return $q.reject(error);
}
```

Alternatively you could throw inside the catch which also cause the promise to be rejected

```
function getPersonsFailed(error) {
    throw(error);
}
```

This is useful reading I think:
https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970

Comment: Is there nothing in the failstate we can return without involving $q? How is $http supposed to work normally? I'm hoping that when a promise in the promise chain is rejected it bubbles backwards without having to manually reject.

Comment: The catch basically gives you an opportunity to intercept the error an decide what you want to do with it. For example, there might be a case where you manually resolve with a cached response after a failed http attempt. If you want it to bubble up without any rethrow then just don't include a catch.

Answer (score 1):

After some research i found out why you got this strange behavior.

The thing to know is that `promise.catch()` return a totaly new promise that is `resolved` at the end of your `getPersonsFailed` function.

To avoid this, you'll need to return a rejected promise.

```
function getPersonsFailed(error) {
    //Do some logic here to handle your error in your service
    return $q.reject(error);
}
```

You could also write your resolve a lot smaller like this (but maybe your syntax was intentional)

```
    resolve: {
       persons: personService.getPersons(),
       jobs: jobService.getJobs()
    }
```

Your server responses will be injectable as `persons` and `jobs` in your controller.

If you're not doing anything else in your .catch() method, i would recommend you to simply remove it.

Hope it helped.

Comment: If I resolve that way will the functions get run in parallel like with the $q.all?

Comment: @IngóVals Yup, resolve if basically calling $q.all() on the object you're giving to him and then add the resolve result of each property available as dependency injection